# Visual Studio custom HTML snippet not working in ascx file?

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I followed the walkthrough at Microsoft to create a VS 2013 snippet. It was to add a shortcut for some css class properties I have to enter often.

I put the language type property at "html" since none of the other options applied.

I imported them into a new folder inside the Code Snippets folder called "Steve".

They do not show up in the `.aspx` and `.ascx` files I have to edit.  If I create a dummy `.html` file, it works.  So I assume the language setting needs to change.  I've Googled it though and can't find what it should be.

**UPDATE:**  I also need to use this in html strings in JS files, if possible.

Here's the snippet, as is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
 <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
  <Header>
    <Title>Button Default</Title>
    <Author>Steve Lombardi</Author>
    <Description>Add a design system default button class</Description>
    <Shortcut>btnd</Shortcut>
</Header>
<Snippet>
  <Code Language="HTML">
    <![CDATA[class="btn btn-default" ]]>
  </Code>
</Snippet>
```

Comment: Could you please share the solution if you were able to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to:

1. use `<Code Language="asp">`
2. save the file in the folder: `Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Code Snippets\Visual Web Developer\My HTML Snippets`

And I have been able to insert the snippet, althought it seems very slow to update the snippet every time I edit it.
Here is a working sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>bsmodal</Title>
      <Shortcut>bsmodal</Shortcut>
      <Description>Code snippet per l'inserimento di finestra modale Bootstrap</Description>
      <Author>Francesco !Formentz! Formenti</Author>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal>
          <ID>modalid</ID>
          <ToolTip>ID della finestra modale</ToolTip>
          <Default>myId</Default>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>labeltext</ID>
          <ToolTip>Testo dell'etichetta</ToolTip>
          <Default>Testo dell'etichetta</Default>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="asp">
<![CDATA[
<div class="modal fade" id="$modalid$" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="$modalid$Label">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <nsc:NSUpdatePanel ID="$modalid$UpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" class="modal-content">
          <Triggers>
              <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="$modalid$Save" EventName="Click" />
          </Triggers>
          <ContentTemplate>
              <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="<%= EdiNova.App_GlobalResources.Loc.GenericModalCloseText %>"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="$modalid$Label">$labeltext$</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">$end$
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <div class="pull-left">
                      <asp:LinkButton ID="$modalid$Delete" runat="server" OnClick="$modalid$Delete_Click" CssClass="btn btn-warning" meta:resourcekey="$modalid$Delete" ValidationGroup="$modalid$Delete"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i> <%= EdiNova.App_GlobalResources.Loc.ModelDeleteCaption %></asp:LinkButton>
                  </div>
                  <div class="pull-right">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><%= EdiNova.App_GlobalResources.Loc.GenericModalCloseText %></button>
                      <asp:LinkButton ID="$modalid$Save" runat="server" OnClick="$modalid$Save_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary" meta:resourcekey="$modalid$Save" ValidationGroup="$modalid$Edit"><i class="fas fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i> <%= EdiNova.App_GlobalResources.Loc.ModelSaveCaption %></asp:LinkButton>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </ContentTemplate>
      </nsc:NSUpdatePanel>
  </div>
</div>
]]></Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```